# MySql comments for the columns of a view?

Tags: mysql

**Is it possible in MySql to store comments for the columns of a view?**

I know how to add comments to normal tables and columns but I am not sure if it is possible to do so for views. All I know is that views (for some aspects) behave just like a table and for this reason it is possible to run a query as such:

```
SELECT 
  column_name, column_comment 
FROM 
  information_schema.columns 
WHERE 
  table_name='myview';
```

But I don't know how to add the comment in the first place and haven't found a solution yet!

The reason I am doing this is that I am storing metadata for my application in the comment field and I would like tables and views to be identical.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the create view syntax there is no way currently to add comments to the "columns" of a view even if the columns of a view are present in the information_schema.columns table:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-view.html

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can add comments to the view "columns", but you can use the view to retrieve comments from the underlying table, use SHOW COLUMNS as you would when querying a table.

Comment: It has to be the syntax with the FULL keyword to see comments
SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM mytable;

Answer (score 2):

Mysql has no metadata for view columns:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/views-table.html

So answer is NO.

Comment: All column meta data (both table columns and view columns) seems to be stored in the information_schema.columns table
(http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/columns-table.html).

Whilst the table you mention seems to be the "view" equivalent table of information_schema.tables which also does not show column information...

Answer (score 1):

We're up to version 5.7, and this feature still hasn't been implemented, even though it has been requested several times. There are four active tickets related to this functionality:

```
http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=5159
http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=64045
http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=52429
http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=15344
```

...and several marked as duplicates: http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=19602 , http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=19602 , http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=13109 , http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=14369 , http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=11082 , http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=42870 , http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=38137 , http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=38137 , http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=30729

If you are interested in this issue, go to the four active tickets, click the "affects me" button, and also add a comment, asking if anyone is working on this feature.

This will add visibility, and increase the likelyhood of it being implemented.

Answer (score 0):

-- A view shows the column comments of the underlying table.

```
-- this does not show column comments
SHOW COLUMNS FROM zztable_vw;

-- this shows column comments from the underlying table
SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM zztable_vw;

CREATE TABLE `zztable` (
-- A SQL statement comment. Not stored with the table. Just documents the create table code
  `zz_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'unique primary key. auto increment',
  `zz_descr` varchar(255) NOT NULL COMMENT 'descriptive name. must be unique if not null',
  PRIMARY KEY (`zz_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `zz_descr_UNIQUE` (`zz_descr`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='a table demonstrating table, column, and view comments. ';

-- select the table from information_schema
SELECT table_type, table_name, table_rows, table_comment
FROM information_schema.tables ta
WHERE ta.table_name LIKE 'zztable%'
ORDER BY ta.table_type, ta.table_name;

-- select the table_columns from information_schema
SELECT ta.table_type, co.table_name, co.column_name, co.column_comment
FROM information_schema.columns co
JOIN information_schema.tables ta
  ON co.table_name = ta.table_name
WHERE co.table_name LIKE 'zztable%'
ORDER BY ta.table_type, co.table_name, co.ordinal_position;

-- create a view over the commented table
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW zztable_vw
AS
SELECT zz_id, zz_descr
FROM zztable;
```

-- now run the information_schema queries again to see the new view in the results

-- information_schema.tables query does not show table-level comments

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>table_type</th>
    <th>table_name</th>
    <th>table_rows</th>
    <th>table_comment</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>BASE TABLE</td>
    <td>zztable</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>a table demonstrating table, column, and view comments.</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>VIEW</td>
    <td>zztable_vw</td>
    <td>NULL</td>
    <td>VIEW</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

-- information_schema.columns query shows underlying table column comments

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>table_type</th>
    <th>table_name</th>
    <th>column_name</th>
    <th>column_comment
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>BASE TABLE</td>
    <td>zztable</td>
    <td>zz_id</td>
    <td>unique primary key. auto increment</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>BASE TABLE</td>
    <td>zztable</td>
    <td>zz_descr</td>
    <td>descriptive name. must be unique if not null</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>VIEW</td>
    <td>zztable_vw</td>
    <td>zz_id</td>
    <td>unique primary key. auto increment</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>VIEW</td>
    <td>zztable_vw</td>
    <td>zz_descr</td>
    <td>descriptive name. must be unique if not null</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```