# Create comments for views in mysql

Tags: mysql, comments, view

I see that the views have a comment field just like the regular tables, but is by default populated with the "VIEW" value.

```
[TABLE_CATALOG] => 
[TABLE_SCHEMA] => xxx
[TABLE_NAME] => view__xxxx
[TABLE_TYPE] => VIEW
[ENGINE] => 
[VERSION] => 
[ROW_FORMAT] => 
[TABLE_ROWS] => 
[AVG_ROW_LENGTH] => 
[DATA_LENGTH] => 
[MAX_DATA_LENGTH] => 
[INDEX_LENGTH] => 
[DATA_FREE] => 
[AUTO_INCREMENT] => 
[CREATE_TIME] => 
[UPDATE_TIME] => 
[CHECK_TIME] => 
[TABLE_COLLATION] => 
[CHECKSUM] => 
[CREATE_OPTIONS] => 
[TABLE_COMMENT] => VIEW
```

When I am trying to create a view with a comment I get an error.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW view__x AS
SELECT 
 * 
FROM `some_table`  
COMMENT = 'some comment'
```

Is there a way to modify the comment field or that field is used internally for something else and should stay like it is?

I've added a [feature request](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=64045) to mysql.

Comment: MySQL does not support comments on views - you are out of luck.

Comment: +1 for good question and the feature request! Also, comments for columns should be implemented, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8865046/mysql-comments-for-the-columns-of-a-view

Answer (score 34):

According to the create view syntax there is no way currently to add comment a view:

- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.1/en/create-view.html

This feature has been requested several times. There are four active tickets related to this functionality:

- http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=5159
- http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=64045
- http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=52429
- http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=15344

...and several marked as duplicates: http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=19602 , http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=19602 , http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=13109
, http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=14369 , http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=11082
, http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=42870 , http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=38137
, http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=38137 , http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=30729

If you are interested in this issue, go to the four active tickets, click the "affects me" button, and also add a comment, asking if anyone is working on this feature.

This will add visibility, and increase the likelyhood of it being implemented.

Update - I posted this comment in December 2013. At that time version was 5.7. As of August 2023, the latest version is 8.1 and there has been no change to the CREATE VIEW documentation page.

Comment: Thanks for the links. It's odd that (three of) those four aren't marked as duplicates as well.

Comment: Wow! Those 4 tickets are still open. One of them was created in 2004!

Answer (score 7):

I had a similar need, and one way I hacked this in MySQL was to add a truthy predicate in the `WHERE` clause that served as documentation.  I admit this is hacky, but wouldn't you agree any documentation is better than no documentation at all?  Once nice side-effect of doing your commentary this way will survive a `mysqldump`.  As far as I know, the optimizer will not be hindered by the extra truthy predicate.

Example view creation:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW high_value_employees AS
SELECT *
FROM `employees`
WHERE salary >= 200000
AND 'comment' != 'This view was made by Josh at the request of an important VP who wanted a concise list of who we might be overpaying. Last modified on 26 July 2019.';
```

And then viewing the documentation ...

```
> SHOW CREATE TABLE high_value_employees \G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
                View: high_value_employees
         Create View: CREATE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED DEFINER=`jhuber`@`%` SQL SECURITY 
DEFINER VIEW `high_value_employees` AS select `employees`.`salary` AS `salary` from
`employees` where ((`employees`.`salary` >= 200000) and ('comment' <> 'This view was
made by Josh at the request of an important VP who wanted a concise list of who we
might be overpaying. Last modified on 26 July 2019.'))
character_set_client: utf8mb4
collation_connection: utf8mb4_general_ci
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Nice workaround. It's ridiculous that this still hasn't been implemented after all these years.

Answer (score 0):

You can home brew comments on views by creating a table in your schema to store the comment on each view. Then join information_schema.tables to the new table.

```
-- A view does not show the table-level comments of the underlying table.
-- nor can a view have view-level comments

CREATE TABLE `zztable` (
-- A SQL statement comment. Not stored with the table. Just documents the create table code
  `zz_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'unique primary key. auto increment',
  `zz_descr` varchar(255) NOT NULL COMMENT 'descriptive name. must be unique if not null',
  PRIMARY KEY (`zz_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `zz_descr_UNIQUE` (`zz_descr`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='a table demonstrating table, column, and view comments. ';

-- select the table from information_schema
SELECT table_type, table_name, table_rows, table_comment
FROM information_schema.tables ta
WHERE ta.table_name LIKE 'zztable%'
ORDER BY ta.table_type, ta.table_name;

-- create a view over the commented table
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW zztable_vw
AS
SELECT zz_id, zz_descr
FROM zztable;

-- now run the information_schema queries again to see the new view in the results
-- MySQL does not allow view-level comments. 

-- create a new table to contain the view-level comments
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `schema_view` (
  `schema_view_id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'unique primary key. auto increment. ',
  `schema_view_name` VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL COMMENT 'view name matches information_schema.tables.table_name for VIEW',
  `schema_view_comment` VARCHAR(2048) NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'the descriptive purpose of the view. ',
  PRIMARY KEY (`schema_view_id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB
COMMENT = 'contains comments for views since MySQL does not store view-level comments. Use this in a join on schema_view_name to information_schema.tables.table_name';

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX `schema_view_name_UNIQUE` ON `schema_view` (`schema_view_name` ASC);

-- insert a view comment
SELECT * FROM schema_view;

INSERT INTO schema_view
(schema_view_name, schema_view_comment)
VALUES ('zztable_vw' , 'a demonstration of documenting view metadata with comments');
COMMIT;

-- modify the query to join to the new schema_view table
-- select the view from information_schema joined to the new table
SELECT ta.table_type, ta.table_name, ta.table_rows, 
    -- show different comments based on table_type
    CASE 
        WHEN ta.table_type = 'BASE TABLE' THEN ta.table_comment
        WHEN ta.table_type = 'VIEW' THEN sv.schema_view_comment
        ELSE NULL
    END AS schema_comment,
    ta.table_comment, 
    sv.schema_view_comment
FROM information_schema.tables ta
-- Show view comments if it exists.
LEFT OUTER JOIN schema_view sv
  ON ta.table_name = sv.schema_view_name
WHERE ta.table_name LIKE 'zztable%'
ORDER BY ta.table_type, ta.table_name;

-- simplify future queries by creating a view
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW `schema_table_vw`
AS
SELECT ta.table_type, ta.table_name, ta.table_rows, 
    -- show different comments based on type
    CASE 
        WHEN ta.table_type = 'BASE TABLE' THEN ta.table_comment
        WHEN ta.table_type = 'VIEW' THEN sv.schema_view_comment
        ELSE NULL
    END AS schema_comment
FROM information_schema.tables ta
-- Show view comments if it exists.
LEFT OUTER JOIN schema_view sv
  ON ta.table_name = sv.schema_view_name
WHERE ta.table_schema = 'my_schema'
ORDER BY ta.table_type, ta.table_name;
```

-- view-level and table-level comments now show in schema_comment

```html
<table width="200" border="1">
  <tr>
    <th scope="col">table_type</th>
    <th scope="col">table_name</th>
    <th scope="col">table_rows</th>
    <th scope="col">schema_comment</th>
    <th scope="col">table_comment</th>
    <th scope="col">schema_view_comment</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>BASE TABLE</td>
    <td>zztable</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>a table demonstrating table, column, and view comments.</td>
    <td>a table demonstrating table, column, and view comments.</td>
    <td>NULL</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>VIEW</td>
    <td>zztable_vw</td>
    <td>NULL</td>
    <td>a demonstration of documenting view metadata with comments</td>
    <td>VIEW</td>
    <td>a demonstration of documenting view metadata with comments</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I wish that could mark the version of views in development so that I can keep track of the different versions in other environments.
My solution is simple: I just add a constant field containing the version to the field list. I enjoy the advantage of having the view version accompanying every retrieved view record.

```
VIEW `myview` AS
    SELECT 
        '2022-10-11' AS `ViewVersion`,
....
```