# Comments in MySql view scripts

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to do so? I've tried multiple gui(mysql workbench, navicat, toad for mysql) and none of them save the comments like this:

```
 -- something important
 select .....
-- something else important
```

etc.

Is there a setting I am passing by or is this something that simply cannot be done? I ask since TOAD for Oracle saves what I posted in the code block above.

Comment: @Wrikken I just tried that and it does not show up in `SHOW CREATE VIEW`

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I went to test it & found the same thing, already deleted the comment.

Comment: It's too bad if the comments can't be saved.  There is a `COMMENT` directive for stored procedures, but it is not in the `CREATE VIEW` spec.

Comment: This appears to to the case, which is atrocious. Comments are important, especially with views considering they are seldom looked it. I find this to the a serious flaw in MySql.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/8891858/2387525

Answered in that post.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/56264921/2387525

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `mysql` command line client *will* save comments for EVENTs, FUNCTIONs, PROCEDUREs, TRIGGERs, but only if you include the `--comments` option.

You can always have `mysql` include comments, by creating a `~/.my.cnf` file with the following:

```
[mysql]
comments=1
```

Unfortunately, MySQL doesn't seem to preserve comments for VIEWs, even if this option is provided.

The only way I have determined to store comments inside a VIEW, is to include a dummy string at the end of the `ORDER BY` fields. For example:

```
CREATE
DEFINER = `root`@`localhost`
SQL SECURITY INVOKER
VIEW  
ex
AS
SELECT
*
FROM 
mysql.user
ORDER BY
user,
'a comment can go here';
```

Visit the [MySQL Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-command-options.html#option_mysql_comments) for more details.

Before MySQL 5.1, you could use MySQL-specific comments (`/*! a comment */`) inside `VIEW`s, but that "feature" was removed in 5.1 and letter. See [here](http://rpbouman.blogspot.com/2006/12/mysql-stored-routines-and-command-line.html) for more details.

Comment: There is an enhancement request for supporting comments in views. Anybody who comes across this, please click "affects me" in http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=30729 .