# MySQL Workbench 6.2 removes all my comments after creation a view

Tags: mysql, view, comments, workbench

Could anybody help me with Workbench which removes all the comments from the sql script after creation a view.

What is it - a bug or an option?
I really need comments and I want to keep them.

Comment: Please clarify. Are you saying that the `SHOW CREATE VIEW viewname` query doesn't show the comments that were in the original `CREATE VIEW` source code?  That's true; it's a MySQL limitation, not a Workbench limitation; there's no place in the data dictionary to store comments with views. There is such a place for tables.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13846441/comments-in-mysql-view-scripts 

Answered in that post.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/56264921/2387525

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a MySQL limitation, not a Workbench limitation; there's no place in the data dictionary to store comments with views.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if what your asking was a bug that has been fixed, but I did discover that the parser in MySQL Workbench 8 will strip out comments placed before the create statement.  For example this comment will be removed:

```
/*
* this is a comment
*/
create or replace view my_view(column1, column2, ...);
```

But a comment placed after the create statement persists:

```
create or replace view my_view(column1, column2, ...);
/*
* this is a comment
*/
```

Comment: Hmmm. Very interesting... I'll check it. Thanks