# How do I comment an SQL view permanently?

Tags: mysql, sql, view, mariadb, comments

I'm looking for a way to permanently comment a MySQL view (MariaDB) so that third parties have the ability to understand what I was trying to accomplish with the SQL query.
Currently, the comment is deleted from the query as soon as I submit it. I am using PhpStorm if that should matter.

Thanks a lot
Cheyos

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create comments for views in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8891858/create-comments-for-views-in-mysql)

Comment: This feature request turns 18 this year: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=5159

Comment: Creating a MariaDB [JIRA](https://jira.mariadb.org) issue would be a good step. I can't see one that exists. [MDEV-13110](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-13110] mentions it in passing but not the same. MariaDB added `COMMENT`s on databases less that 18 years ago due to user requests (and an external contribution I believe MDEV-307). [MDEV-13805](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-13805) also relevant. [Contributions welcome](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/contributing-code/).